# Cypress is unable to find Vagrant provided server in Github Actions

Tags: cypress, vagrant-provision

Relevant link: https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-webui/pull/186

I am trying to run `cypress` tests on `ipa` server installed in Vagrant. I output the Vagrant's IP after the installation to `/etc/hosts`, which, I presume, is a host file used by GitHub runner.
However, `cypress` does not seem to be able to find the running server.
Previously (about a month ago), the runners were using `192.168.x.y` IP and the vagrant provisioning has been consistently running on an assigned static address. This has changed recently and the vagrant provisioning is running on `10.0.x.y` address. With `192.168.x.y` address, `cypress` had no issue finding the server.

What I tried:

- `http` and `https` for `baseUrl` param of cypress config
- setting `host` with the IP as a `env` param for cypress step (see `gating.yml` in the PR above)
- using `wait-on` with server's url (`server.ipa.demo`) in `gating.yml`

Relevant code:

[`cypress.config.ts`](https://github.com/miskopo/freeipa-webui/blob/57dfd5538cefd337d6f61313173ee014a93e50bc/cypress.config.ts)

```
e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    baseUrl: "http://server.ipa.demo",
```

[`gating.yml`](https://github.com/miskopo/freeipa-webui/blob/57dfd5538cefd337d6f61313173ee014a93e50bc/.github/workflows/gating.yml)

```
      - name: Cache Vagrant boxes
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.vagrant.d/boxes
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-vagrant-${{ hashFiles('Vagrantfile') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-vagrant-

      - name: Cleanup running Vagrant boxes in case they are running
        run: vagrant destroy --force

      - name: Run vagrant up
        run: vagrant up --no-provision

      - name: Run vagrant provision
        run: vagrant provision

      - name: Put IPA Server's IP to /etc/hosts
        run: sudo echo "$(vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I") server.ipa.demo" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

      - name: Save server's IP address to env
        run: echo "SERVER_IP=$(vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I")" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Print exported variable
        run: echo "$SERVER_IP"

      - name: Run Cypress tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          browser: firefox
          env: host="https://${{ env.SERVER_IP  }}"
```

The error:

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > https://server.ipa.demo/

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your baseUrl.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
We will try connecting to it 1 more time...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue using following steps:

1. replace `mac-os` runner by `ubuntu`.

When running `Vagrant` from `mac-os`, Vagrant was assigned only `10.0.2.15` address, which was not usable for connecting to the server running in `Vagrant`.

When using `ubuntu`, `Vagrant` gets assigned both `10.0.2.15` and `192.168.x.y` addresses, where `192...` works in the internal network.

2. For putting servers IP address into `/etc/hosts`, I have used following step

```
      - name: Put IPA Server's IP to /etc/hosts
        run: sudo echo "$(vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I|sed 's/10\.0\.2\.15//'") server.ipa.demo" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

You can see [PR#186](https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-webui/pull/186) for details.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you just need to edit `/etc/hosts`.

This is a section from my file, shows the mapping of real IP to named address.

```js
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.83 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.83 gateway.docker.internal
```

From your description you currently have the following mapping, and that used to work

```js
192.168.x.y server.ipa.demo
```

but now the IP has changed you just need to edit the file (as administrator) to

```js
10.0.x.y server.ipa.demo
```

Note that Cypress is just pinging the `baseUrl` you provide, and leaving it up to the system to find the server, so there's nothing to configure from the Cypress end.

---

I notice from the pull request you reference above that you already know this, so I'm wondering what you are looking for - is it a way to bypass `/etc/hosts`?

```js
# Needed by Cypress - optional if you edit your /etc/hosts
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
```

---

Perhaps you can do it with this config [github-action/.github/workflows
/example-config.yml](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/blob/60b56d86873dc97e25850d275725ed1f0ca626d3/.github/workflows/example-config.yml#L25)

```js
      - name: Run Cypress tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          browser: firefox
          config: baseUrl=https://${{ env.SERVER_IP  }}
```

or assign the env var to Cypress config in `cypress.config.js`

```js
const {defineConfig} = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.baseUrl = process.env.SERVER_IP
      return config 
    }
  }
})
```